# Acess Denied for file

Tags: c#, android, json

I writing app for android and need to write json to .txt file.
.txt file is on  the project root

Now I parse json like this

```
string url2 = "http://new.murakami.ua/?mkapi=getProducts";
JsonValue json = await FetchAsync(url2);

private async Task<JsonValue> FetchAsync(string url)
{
    // Create an HTTP web request using the URL:
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(new Uri(url));
    request.ContentType = "application/json";
    request.Method = "GET";

    // Send the request to the server and wait for the response:
    using (WebResponse response = await request.GetResponseAsync())
    {
        // Get a stream representation of the HTTP web response:
        using (Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream())
        {
            // Use this stream to build a JSON document object:
            JsonValue jsonDoc = await Task.Run(() => JsonObject.Load(stream));
            //dynamic data = JObject.Parse(jsonDoc[15].ToString);

            Console.Out.WriteLine("Response: {0}", jsonDoc.ToString());

            // Return the JSON document:
            return jsonDoc;
        }
```

I tried to use this:

```
StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(@"\myfile.txt");
sw.Write(json.ToString());
sw.Close();
```

but it says `System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path "/\myfile.txt" is denied.`

How I can parse json to file?

Comment: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" /> - is this set in your manifest file?

Comment: yes I set this permission
Maybe trouble with code?

Comment: Sorry, I mean WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE. Do you use Xamarin?

Comment: Yes< using Xamarin @Toddams

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try change a path to the private directory of your application

```
string path = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
string filename = System.IO.Path.Combine(path, "myfile.txt");

using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(filename, true))
{
    //Write your data here
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: If I has file in root of project, what path I need to write?

Comment: Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal type maps to the path /data/data/[your.package.name]/files. This is a private directory to your application.

Comment: I have one more question, if i want to read from this file i use StreamReader?

Comment: It is not necessary, you can use either static methods from System.IO.File or StreamReader